# How did Michael Scofield know where to look for his letters?

Tags: prison-break

In *Prison Break* season 5 episode 8, Michael, Lincoln and Sheeba come to the house at Ithaca where Sarah and Jacob lives.

After getting off the vehicle, Michael suddenly sees their post box named Ness 1990. Then suddenly Michael leans to the drain alongside the road near post box and says that's why Sarah didn't get any of his letters.

How did he know already to where to look at exactly?

In a flashback scene, after that, it shows that Jacob opens a letter every day and put Michael's signature origami swan into the drain pipe.

But how did Michael know exactly that Jacob did it? It could be numerous reasons Sarah didn't get Michael's letters, or maybe she did get them but didn't have any intention or chance, or doesn't know how to reply to those letters.

**Is there anything I missed here or else how did Michael know exactly where to look at the first glance of the post box in front of Sarah's house?**

Comment: I didn't see the episode yet but, from your description, it seems to be an educated guess: if your partner's presumed dead husband and father of her child was sending her letters, wouldn't you throw them in the nearest place where she had no chance to find them?

Comment: People doesn't usually read their letter right after they took letters from the box. they usually go inside and read. and also drain pipe is not a good place to dump letters. burn the little piece of paper is rather better option, and i think Poseidon should do such thing rather than just throw everything at the same place, don't you think?

Comment: Is there nobody who can help with my question? :(

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit reason given.

However Michael and Jacob operate in a very similar manner, and often come to the same conclusions when given the same parameters to work with. So one possible answer is he checked the drain because that is where he would have thrown them if the situations were reversed.

I think it's also a bit of reference to season 1, whereby Michael in the original season used the origami to figure out the state of the pipes from the medical room. Drain, origami, let's give that another spin.

Comment: yes they both operated a little similarly. But in that scene, michael goes straight to the drain like he already knew a long ago. what you say may be possible, but unlikely.
Season one situation is different. yes it reminds the viewer and yes its michael's signature swan. but I don't think season one's incidents are relevent here

Comment: Agreed - my first line is really the answer then - "there is no explicit reason given"

Comment: Not the answer i was looking for, but thanks for your help @Chris. appreciate it :)

Comment: Haha no worries, and trust me, I agree. I believe because the season was never planned to be only 9 episodes some things feel rushed

Comment: yeah, although I hope that maybe, just maybe we'll be able to see season 6